# Yii ajaxlink in partial

Tags: ajax, yii, partial

I'm using Yii framework and have small problem.
Then I include to the partial **CHtml::ajaxLink**, link stopping work as ajax, standart click is raised and performs redirect to another page.
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Check to make sure the action is getting called properly - instead of renderPartial, have it return some text and exit. If that doesn't work, it's probably a js issue. Check your rendered HTML to see if anything is amiss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a supposition, but turn processOutput on when using partialRender with javascript. It's the fourth parameter when calling renderPartial:

`$this->renderPartial('_view',array(params...),false,true)`

ProcessOutput allows you to also load javascript when rendering with asynchronous calls or other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Turn firebug on and check for js errors. If there are any, post them here

There was something wrong with yii CHtml::ajax implementation, and it caused me similar bug to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not finishing document right?
try with:

```
 Yii::app()->end();
```

And check differences in generated HTML between old version (which worked) and this one.
Maybe some js lib not included?