# Yii render partial with x-editable does not re-init fields

Tags: yii, renderpartial, x-editable

We are using may x-editable fields (http://x-editable.demopage.ru/) in a view. Everything works fine until we call the controller via ajax, leading to a partial rendering of the view

```
$this->renderPartial(...);
```

The website gets refershed, but all x-editable fields disappear because the global script of the view, which seems to initialize all x-editable fields via javascript, does not get called.

I also checked the returned code from the renderPartial method, it also does not contain the script needed to initialize.

So, my question is: is is not possible to render partial with x-editable? Or can i re-load global javascript code somehow?

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753143/yii-ajaxlink-in-partial/6754862#6754862

Comment: Arr, i set the 3rd parameter to true and did not "see" the 4th. Thanks a lot! Script languages suck.

Comment: Thanks for tophers link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753143/yii-ajaxlink-in-partial/6754862#6754862

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$this->renderPartial('_view', array(), False, True);
```